# HTTPClient and PostMethod

Tags: java, apache-commons-httpclient

So I ran into a problem and the service support asked me to support them with the HTML.
So I need to get the equivalent HTML that is generated by

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
PostMethod post = new PostMethod( "https://www.url.to/post-to" );
NameValuePair[] params = {
                new NameValuePair( "NAME", name ),
                new NameValuePair( "EMAIL", email ),
for( NameValuePair param : params ){
   post.setParameter(param.getName(), param.getValue());
}
```

Is it possible to get it as HTML or get the request sent as a string, with all the headers etc?

Answer (score 1):

If you use some logging framework, Apache HttpClient can be configured to log requests and responses which go through it, see [Wire logging](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/logging.html). Judging by the documentation, if logging framework is properly setup, this should be enough to enable it

```
System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.Log", "org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SimpleLog");

System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.showdatetime", "true");

System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.log.httpclient.wire", "debug");

System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.log.org.apache.commons.httpclient", "debug");
```

**EDIT**

These settings are ok if you use `Apache Commons Logging` as logging framework. Above mentioned link also contains examples for setting this up for `log4j` and `java.util.logging`.

Answer (score 0):

You could write an equivalent HTML form, that sends the same two parameters to the same URL.

However, if you're opening a support ticket for a problem caused by this connection, an HTML will probably not be very helpful, because a browser may be sending different headers to the URL even if the request body is the same.

You can get the request headers from the `post` variable, using `post.getRequestHeaders()`. It returns an array of type `Header[]`, which you'll have to translate into strings. The message body is probably easy to reconstruct from the parameters by urlencoding the values. The body is always in the form `NAME=urlencodedname&EMAIL=urlencodedemail`.